How to multiply a number by a row index to obtain a data range in Excel?
I wish to create a range that implies multiplying the row index number by a constant, but it seems this is not done in a rather straightfoward way. I´m used to work in OriginPro, and it is very simple to achieve this, but I am oblivious on how to do this in Excel - but there must be a way, I am sure of it!
Remember, I am interested in the row index, not in the value of any specific row/column or cell itself.

You can use the worksheet functions =Row() and =Column(), as in the following example:
="row equals [" & ROW(E6) & "], column equals [" & COLUMN(E6) & "]"

This gives the following result:

